# Blazor css how to show Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality header

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have implemented in a Blazor Server Side project a Bootstrap template and I don't link the css style of the standard Microsoft template.

What I miss are the classes that show/hides the upper header with "Attempting to reconnect to the server..." and then "Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality" that comes when I recompile the project (I use the Ctrl-F5 method to have a quite similar edit&continue pattern)

note that my background goes white with opacity 0.8, but not the header of my bootstrap template, so I guess there is something with z-index or else that hides the Blazor Reload banner

can you point me what I have to maintain/add from the standard css ?
(I already added the #blazor-error-ui and #blazor-error-ui .dismiss classes but those are for the lower footer when there are exceptions)

Thanks

Comment: Try inspecting the vanilla template with the devtools to see what classes it uses so you can find their content on the vanilla stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

added this on my custom.css; the inline style added z-index:1000, probably it was not enough

```
#components-reconnect-modal
{
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```